# Bayes Estimator/Bayes Rule for multiple loss functions?

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, bayesian, parameter-estimation

The following is a homework question so I do not need a full answer, but I do need help understanding the question.

**The Question**:
A coin with an unknown probability of heads ($\theta$) is flipped once, and you observe the result. On the second flip, you can choose the following actions:

- $a_1$: predict the same side
- $a_2$: predict the opposite side
- $a_3$: do not play

If you are correct, you get \$2. If you are incorrect, you lose \$1. If you don't play you net $0.

Assuming a Uniform Prior on $\theta$, what is the [Bayes Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator#Example:_estimating_p_in_a_binomial_distribution)?

**My Attempt**: The Bayes Rule in the context of our class is typically an estimator ($\hat\theta_{Bayes}$) that minimizes the posterior expected loss of an action:
$$\hat\theta_{Bayes}={\arg\min}\int_{\Theta}\ell(\theta,a)p(\theta|x)d\theta $$

First, we find the posterior. The likelihood follows $p(x|\theta)\sim Binomial(2, \theta)$, and the prior can be expressed as $p(\theta)\sim Beta(1,1)$. Using the Beta-Binomial model, our posterior is thus: $p(\theta|x)\sim Beta(x+1, 1+2-x)$

The loss, however, is dependent on the choice of action (negative loss represents a gain):
$$\begin{align*}
l(\theta,a_1)&=-\$2p(x=0,2|\theta)+\$1p(x=1|\theta)\\
l(\theta,a_2)&=-\$2p(x=1|\theta)+\$1p(x=0,2|\theta)\\
l(\theta,a_3)&=\$0
\end{align*}$$

What I do not understand is: I am used to seeing one loss function (for instance, MSE or absolute loss).

In the case above, is the Bayes Rule/Bayes Estimator unique to each action, or is there one Bayes Rule that satisfies this problem for all actions? Stated differently, how do I incorporate the fact that there are different loss functions into the problem (or have I incorrectly described the loss function)?

Comment: This  is not about a Bayes estimator, but a Bayesian decision.  You have three possible choices, each of which has its own expected loss (or gain), so if you work this out for each one, all you need to do is choose the one with the lowest expected loss (i.e.  highest expected gain)

Comment: Thank you - our course used Bayes Rule/Bayes Estimator somewhat interchangeably and it has made the assignments confusing.

Comment: Personally I would start by finding the posterior density for $\theta$ having observed heads in the first flip. Then I would use that to find the expected gain or loss from the various decisions.  The alternative approach of skipping the posterior density and just looking at the prior distribution of matching heads or tails and the expected gains or losses also works and produces the same values (obviously you should guess the second flip is the same as the first)